# Bringing multiple columns into pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I currently have following data structure:

```
    VarA     VarB     VarC
0   08/2005  06/2005  NaN   
1   07/2014  08/2014  09/2014   
2   09/2005  10/2005  01/2004       
3   05/2005  NaN      02/2002
```

I need to bring my data into the following pivot form, that is a table with three columns, sorted after ID (the ID is the index), and date:

```
ID Var  Date
0  VarB 06/2005
0  VarA 08/2005
1  VarA 07/2014
1  VarB 08/2014
1  VarC 09/2015
2  VarC 01/2004
2  VarA 09/2005
2  VarB 10/2005
3  VarC 02/2002
3  VarA 05/2005
```

What's the best approach to solve this with pandas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `df.melt()` or `df.stack().reset_index()`

Comment: `melt()` seems to sort the variables only. However, `stack().reset_index()` seems to go about into the right direction, but it creates a new level_0 and level_1 variable?

Comment: ``df.rename_axis(index = 'ID').melt(ignore_index=False, var_name = 'Var', value_name = 'Date').sort_index().dropna().reset_index()``? or ``df.rename_axis(columns='Var', index='ID').stack().rename('Date').reset_index()``

Comment: @Christopher Yes, try what sammywemmy proposes.  See if that gets you close.  And you can aways `rename(columns={'level_0':'ID', 'level_1':'Var'})` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, almost solved! How exactly can I implement that the Var for each ID is sorted in order by `Date` (ascending)? Currently the order of items seems to be random, except for the ID which his sorted ascending? Note: My Date column has format datetime64[ns].